# Vue dragula - drop event listener called multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dragula

I'm trying to build a web app with draggable elements using Vue.js and the vue-dragula framework. In the app, I'm trying to have multiple containers with elements that can be dragged across the containers.

In App.vue

```html
<template>
   <div v-for="container in containers">
      <container/>
   </div>
</template>
```

In Container.vue

```html
<template>
   <div v-dragula="elements" bag="first-bag">
      <div v-for="element in elements" :key="element.id">
         <element v-bind="element"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
   mounted() {
      Vue.$dragula.$service.eventBus.$on('drop', () => {
         console.log('Dropped');
      });
   }
}
```

I'm trying to enable an event listener that's able to detect when an element has been dropped. While the current event listener method works, it is called multiple times. Specifically, it is called the length of the containers array. For example, if containers is an array of length 6, 'Dropped' is logged 6 times. How do I have it so that the event listener for drop is only called once?

Answer (score 0):

My solution below.

App.vue

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(container, containerIndex) in containers">
      <container :containerIndex="containerIndex" />
   </div>
</template>
```

In Container.vue

```
<template>
   <div v-dragula="elements" :bag="'first-bag-'+containerIndex">
      <div v-for="element in elements" :key="element.id">
         <element v-bind="element"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      props: ['containerIndex'],
      mounted() {
         Vue.$dragula.$service.eventBus.$on('drop', ([bag, curElmt, allElmts]) => {
            if (bag == 'first-bag-'+this.containerIndex) {
               console.log('Dropped'); // This line is not repate based on containers length
            }
         });
      }
   }
<script>
```